# Angular 2 Inner Html Copying Issue

Tags: angular

I am trying to copy an Html table with a button click that I can then paste into an email so as to preserve the formatting,etc.

I tried using **ngx-clipboard** and doing the following:

```
<button [clipboard]="value1.innerHTML.trim()">
            Copy Text 
        </button> 
          <div #value1>
            <p style="background-color:red ">agdfsgasdg</p>
        </div>
```

When I copy this into an email, it pastes the **plain** html text. However if I highlight this #value1 section manually in the browser and paste, it maintains the actual html formatting(and appears the same as it does in the browser), so I am not sure what the difference is between copying in the browser vs. copying using a clipboard component. I would like to be able to maintain the HTML formatting the way that occurs when you highlight a section of html and copy into an email. Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Can you show the clipboard directive? edit:  ah it's ngx-clipboard. nevermind

Comment: Problem is ngx-clipboard uses a hidden textarea so seems it isn't a good fit for your use case. You may need to make your own solution to copy the element's html directly, not via a textarea.

Comment: Thanks for the info! That solution works fine from your link.